# OpenCV not detecting eye even though it detects face and correctly gets left and right halves

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to find the problem in my code and understanding related to opencv and face/eye detection. The full code is here:

https://pastebin.com/s4zCN7gM

The code in the code block is a condensed (comparatively) for where the problem is.

```cpp
//Search for both eyes within the given face image. Returns the eye centers in 'leftEye' and 'rightEye',
// or sets them to (-1,-1) if each eye was not found. Note that you can pass a 2nd eyeCascade if you
// want to search eyes using 2 different cascades. For example, you could use a regular eye detector
// as well as an eyeglasses detector, or a left eye detector as well as a right eye detector.
// Or if you don't want a 2nd eye detection, just pass an uninitialized CascadeClassifier.
// Can also store the searched left & right eye regions if desired.
void detectBothEyes(const Mat &face, CascadeClassifier &eyeCascade1, 
                                     CascadeClassifier &eyeCascade2, 
                                     Point &leftEye, Point &rightEye, 
                                     Rect *searchedLeftEye, 
                                     Rect *searchedRightEye,
                                     String filename) {


  //For default eye.xml or eyeglasses.xml: Finds both eyes in 
  // roughly 40% of detected faces, but does not detect closed eyes.
  const float EYE_SX = 0.16f;
  const float EYE_SY = 0.26f;
  const float EYE_SW = 0.30f;
  const float EYE_SH = 0.28f;

  int leftX = cvRound(face.cols * EYE_SX);
  int topY = cvRound(face.rows * EYE_SY);
  int widthX = cvRound(face.cols * EYE_SW);
  int heightY = cvRound(face.rows * EYE_SH);
  int rightX = cvRound(face.cols * (1.0-EYE_SX-EYE_SW) );  //Start of right-eye corner

  Mat topLeftOfFace = face(Rect(leftX, topY, widthX, heightY));
  Mat topRightOfFace = face(Rect(rightX, topY, widthX, heightY));
  Rect leftEyeRect, rightEyeRect;

  imwrite(filename + "_leftHalfFace.png",topLeftOfFace); 
  imwrite(filename + "_rightHalfFace.png",topRightOfFace); 

  //Search the left region, then the right region using the 1st eye detector.
  detectLargestObject(topLeftOfFace, eyeCascade1, leftEyeRect, 
                      topLeftOfFace.cols);
  cout << "leftEyeRect= "<< endl << " " << leftEyeRect << endl << endl;
  detectLargestObject(topRightOfFace, eyeCascade1, rightEyeRect, 
                      topRightOfFace.cols);
  cout << "rightEyeRect= "<< endl << " " << rightEyeRect << endl << endl;

  //NOTE...there is code here that says if leftEyeRect or rightEyeDetect was not 
  // detected to set
  // to (-1,-1)

}
```

The code is in c++. The code is modified from a sample code that was available with a book.

I am trying to read images and detect face and eyes (and also face recognize). It seems that the face detection is successful consistently on the 20 images (10 tom cruise and 10 emma watson) I tried detecting. But even though I am able to successfully split the detected face into a left and right half (where each half shows the appropriate eye), the eye detection is failing for several images. I don't understand why and what I can do to resolve this?

The problem specifical is in the function detectBothEyes, where the variable leftEyeRect and rightEyeRect both return (-1, -1) (meaning it did not find an eye).

Can anyone point me to the issue or how I can improve detection of eyes?

https://pastebin.com/s4zCN7gM

I expect that the eyes are detected and therefore the variable 'leftEyeRect' and 'rightEyeRect' are not (-1, -1) but instead positive values).

Comment: Please use the link here as the one in the question will expire in a day 
  https://pastebin.com/V64WRNfX

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I went ahead and updated the links in the original question to non-expiring pastebin. https://pastebin.com/s4zCN7gM

Comment: Please include code (preferably a [mcve], click that link to see what that means) in the question itself. The questions and answers here are expected to remain useful even if any links in them go stale.